# What's the most effective way to check for nil in a nested hash

Tags: ruby

I have a large Mash object with lots of nested Mashes. Some of the data I want to get is several layers in like:

```
phone = profile.phone_numbers.all.first.phone_number
title = profile.positions.all.first.title
```

However, phone_numbers or positions may be nil or empty. What's the most effective way of nil checking without having to nil check each level. Is there a general technique to use?

Comment: No, it's actually a Mash. I mention it only because my syntax uses the dot operator. http://rubygems.org/gems/mash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ick](http://ick.rubyforge.org/)'s `maybe` is there to help you!

Use it like this:

```
phone = maybe(profile) {|p| p.phone_numbers.all.first.phone_number}

# or like this. 
phone = profile.maybe.phone_numbers.
                maybe.all.
                maybe.first.
                maybe.phone_number
```

Or you can prefer a simpler solution: [Object#andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/). It functions in a similar way.

```
phone = profile.andand.phone_numbers.
                andand.all.
                andand.first.
                andand.phone_number
```

Comment: Is there a difference between maybe and andand?

Comment: From your point of view, no. They function in a similar way. Updated the post while you posted this comment. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to know is what you want to have happen if an intermediate value is nil. Do you want the value assigned to be nil or another value? Do you want processing to continue or halt or raise an error?

If assigning a nil is acceptable, you can add a `rescue nil` clause to the line:

```
phone = profile.phone_numbers.all.first.phone_number rescue nil
title = profile.positions.all.first.title rescue nil
```

That will return nil, which will be assigned to the variable, and processing will continue. There are some risks to doing that, because if the intervening methods or values are nil, it might be good for you to know it. A nil value usually means something didn't get assigned correctly before execution got to that point, and the rescue will obscure that, making debugging more difficult.

If you want to continue, but have the opportunity to react before continuing, use a standard rescue block:

```
begin
  phone = profile.phone_numbers.all.first.phone_number
rescue Exception => e
  STDERR.puts "Exception handled: #{ e }"
  phone = nil
end
```